# ways to publish pages in github using markdown without having to install jekyll or other tools

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I intend to publish articles on my user page in github. I want to write my articles as markdown files and push them to a branch in my user.github.io repo  and let github automatically generate HTML files for me without having to use a tool like Jekyll . Can it be done ? If so how can I do it ? I pushed a index.markdown files to gh-pages branch but couldnt find any auto-generated html files.

Comment: Can you post a a link to your repo?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/GoWind/GoWind.github.io)

Comment: That's a user page, so use the `master` branch (`gh-pages` branch is only used for project pages).  It seems your markdown file must start with YAML front matter to be processed.

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to generate your html pages from your markdown code, as a static site, in order for your GitHub domain to display said html pages.

One easy way to generate such a site is through the go-based ([go=golang](http://golang.org/)) framework **[Hugo](http://hugo.spf13.com/)** (GitHub site: https://github.com/spf13/hugo).
That means you need to install "other tools" locally to generate those pages from your markdown sources.

The [Hugo documentation site](http://hugo.spf13.com/) itself is generated by Hugo, and published on a [project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages).

See also the GitHub help page "[Creating Project Pages manually](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually)", to add your own html pages in the `gh-pages` branch of your repo.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So now you can generate your files in a subfolder of your main branch.

Comment: Why no?  I'm not sure why https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator didn't work for OP but it clearly should be possible.